# Problem with PUT , alter all tables ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch, put

I would like to explain my problem of the day.

In the following code, everything works properly.

unfortunately when I PUT it changes all the tables in my database.

I would like this to change only the table on which I make my put

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import { CardText, Card, Row, Col, Button } from 'reactstrap';

 const entrypoint = process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENTRYPOINT + '/api';

 class AdminPage extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state= {
 data: [],
 } 
 handleSubmit = (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 const config = {
  method: "PUT",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({livree: new Date().toISOString().slice(11,16)}),
 };

  const url = entrypoint + "/alluserpls";
  fetch(url, config)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    if (res.error) {
      alert(res.error);
    } else {
      alert(`ajouté avec l'ID ${res}!`);
    }
  }).catch(e => {
    console.error(e);

    }).finally(() => this.setState({ redirect: true }));
 }
 getRandom = async () => {

const res = await axios.get(
  entrypoint + "/alluserpls"
)
this.setState({ data: res.data })
}
componentDidMount() {
this.getRandom()
 }

 render() {

 let datas = this.state.data.map((datass, index) => {
   return (
    <div >
      <Col sm="12" key={index} className="wtfFuHereIsForOnlyBackGroundColorForCol12Nice">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
              </Button>
              <CardText className="cardTextForAdminPageForDataName"> Commande de 
              {datass.name}</CardText>
              <Col sm="6">
                <CardText>{datass.alertStyle} </CardText>
              </Col>
      </ Col>
      </div>
     )
   })
  return (
       <div>
          {datas}
        </div>      
   )
 }
}
export default AdminPage
```

that is route on back

```
 app.put('/api/alluserpls', (req, res, ) => {
 // récupération des données envoyées
 const formData = req.body;
 connection.query('UPDATE alluserpls SET ?', formData, err => {
 if (err) {
  // Si une erreur est survenue, alors on informe l'utilisateur de 
l'erreur
  console.log(err);
  res.status(500).send("Erreur lors de la modification des users");
} else {
  // Si tout s'est bien passé, on envoie un statut "ok".
  res.sendStatus(200);
 }
});
});
```

I tried to clean as much as possible
Do you have an idea of how to fix this? Neff

Comment: Why is there only the front end here, from what you say it seems something in the backup doesn't match up. What do you mean when you say it is changing all your tables?

Comment: Hello @Icepickle ,  
I modify, and I add the route of my back .                                                                        {
        "id": 122,
       "created": "08:56",
        "livree": "12:42"
    },
    {
        "id": 123,
        "created": "09:16",
        "livree": "12:42"
    } so he changing Livree id 122 and 123 too

Answer (score 0):

> unfortunately when I PUT it changes all the tables in my database.

I believe you mean it is changing all the **rows** of your table, not all tables.

Your **UPDATE** command does not have any `WHERE` clause or anything else limiting your update to a single row, which means that **all** rows are updated

Comment: Ok I think I understand, can you show me an example with the id?

Comment: No because I don't know what database you are using and also, I don't think you pass the id in your PUT request

Comment: i will use mySql , do you have idea where is need to fix ?

Comment: Yes
1. send the ID of the object you want to change in the JSON request

2. on the server, extract the ID of the object you wish to change from the JSON

3. use that ID in your code for the WHERE clause

Comment: do you have example ? or tuto to show what you say ?